# Can I disable CS1591 while keeping SA1600 for the same line of code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, code-analysis, stylecop

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and moved from the StyleCop extension to the StyleCop Analysers NuGet. After a bit of trouble I've managed to get it working. But observed somehing odd:

If I leave the project build settings at the default (not generating XML documentation file) i get a SA0001 warning (an no warnings for missing xml documentation for closed files). If I select to output the XML documentation (on the Build tab) the SA0001 naturally disappears, and I get a lot of SA160x warnings (also for closed files). The "problem" is that I also see a CS1591 for each SA1600.

I can also set the VS option for Text Editor, C#, Advanced, Enable full solution analysis to see warnings for closed files, but I still get both CS1591 and SA1600 for the same line of code.

In my dream scenario I'd get the SA160x warnings for all files without seeing CS1591 and SA0001. Is that possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

CS1591 is a compiler warning. Just go into your projects settings and add it to the list of warnings to be ignored.

<kbd>Project</kbd> => <kbd>Properties</kbd> => <kbd>Build</kbd> => <kbd>Errors and Warnings</kbd> => <kbd>Supress Warnings</kbd> => enter 1591 in the textbox and save

Comment: One question, can I do it for specific files in the project?

Comment: @Shankar You can write `#pragma warning disable 1591` at the top of the file and `#pragma warning restore 1591` at the bottom of the file. But there is no filter, like say "Don't so this for *.xyz files".

Comment: thanks, but one more constraint for me is that I m trying to do it wothout modifying the source code, is it possible?

Something like [assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Comments", "TI4111:Don't comment out code", Justification = "<Pending>")]

Comment: If I have a multi-project solution, must I do that in every existing project or is there a way to actually do it globally? Using Visual Studio 2022